# Python Scrape website with Requests and lxml..

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests, scrape, pyquery

Using this as a starting point.. 
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Everything works as expected..But,....

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.streetinsider.com/ipo_history.php?type=upcoming')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Gives this error...

```
File "<string>", line unknown
XMLSyntaxError: line 1: Document is empty
```

Using pyquery....

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
from lxml import etree,html
import requests


response = pq(url='http://www.streetinsider.com/ipo_history.php?type=upcoming')

doc = pq(response.content)
```

throws this error...

```
File "<string>", line unknown
XMLSyntaxError: line 1504: Unexpected end tag : h2
```

Any help getting the table from the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some website detects and blocks certain user-agents. (something like web robots.) Web-app behind www.streetinsider.com seems to detect user-agent of python-requests, and (passively) blocks its HTTP request.

You may set user-aget using headers={'User-Agent': ''} parameter of requests.get function call.

```
page = requests.get('http://www.streetinsider.com/ipo_history.php', \
                    headers={'User-Agent': 'tester'}, \
                    params={'type':'upcoming'})
```

Comment: can you get the table... or show that 'page' is not blank....

Comment: Above code receives non-empty HTTP body from the server.